# Navigation Bar buttons

Tags: css, html, nav

The problem I'm having is coming from the topnav leftside with the buttons. For whatever reason it seems they have a bullet point or something in them cause it to have a space and then the word (home,about,etc) and also its not floating all the way to left by the wrapper div.

```
    <nav id = topnav>
        <ul class = leftside>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Photos</li>
            <li>Articles</li>
            <li>Forum</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class = rightside>
            <li><a href="https://facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/instagram.png" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://youtube.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/youtube.png"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

and the CSS portion:

```
        #topnav {
    clear: both;
}

#topnav .leftside li{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background-color: #DCCBCB;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline; font-family: helvetica; font-size:16px; margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 2%;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    list-style: none;
}
#topnav .leftside li:hover {
    background-color: #595454;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
    border: none;
    color: white;
}

#topnav .rightside li {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to post your CSS.

Comment: Try `list-style: none; padding:##px` in your css and adjust the padding to what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
ul {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

.rightside {
    float: right;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LDG7U/

Comment: @user3504417 Make sure to mark this as the answer when you can. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a white space between your inline li.

Try this:

```
ul
{
    font-size: 0;
}
ul li
{
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px; /* or whatever size you need */
}
```